# shortcut to program files (x86) directory

Tags: vim, cmd, command-prompt

On my `win32` system I had this command in Vim to open a vim file in wordpad:

```
silent ! start c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe "%:p"<CR>
```

On my `win64` system this doesn't work. I get this error:

```
error: Windows cannot find `"c:\Program"`
```

Maybe because of the space(s) inside `"Program Files (x86)"` and `"Windows NT"`?

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around your path.
Like so:

`silent ! start "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" "%:p"<CR>`

Answer (score 7):

On 64-bit Windows wordpad.exe won't be in "Program Files (x86)", but in "Program Files". At least it is on my machine.

There are environment variables to find the folder names: "%ProgramFiles%" and "%ProgramFiles(x86)%".

Answer (score 3):

Vim on Windows has a special `!start` (without a space in between) for asynchronous invocation.

And, as always, you need to put double quotes around the path, like this:

```
silent !start "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" "%:p"
```